# Java Modelmapper - how do I map an empty array in the source object?

Tags: java, modelmapper

How do I map an empty array using this model mapping library http://modelmapper.org? If my source object has an empty array in it's hierarchy it doesn't get mapped (or is ignored maybe?). I created a program here to demonstrate: https://onecompiler.com/java/3yktwzjc3

The output is:

**FooDTO before:**

```
FooDTO{name='My foo DTO', bar=BarDTO{name='My foo's bar', jars=[]}}
```

**Foo before:**

```
Foo{name='My Foo', bar=Bar{name='null', jars=[Jar{name='Jar 1'}, Jar{name='Jar 2'}]}}
```

**Foo after:**

```
Foo{name='My foo DTO', bar=Bar{name='My foo's bar', jars=[Jar{name='Jar 1'}, Jar{name='Jar 2'}]}}
```

You can see I map FooDTO -> Foo. The mapping for everything works e.g. the name fields, but the empty 'jars' array in the FooDTO's bar object doesn't get mapped.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write convertors to get the mapping done and add the same in your modelmapper.

EG:

```
Converter<List<JarDTO>, List<Jar>> convertIdentities = new AbstractConverter<List<JarDTO>, List<Jar>>() {
            protected List<Jar> convert(List<JarDTO> source) {
                return source.stream().map(identity -> {
                    Jar nestedIdentity = new Jar();
                    nestedIdentity.setName(identity.getName());
                    return nestedIdentity;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        };
        modelMapper.addConverter(convertIdentities);
```